# Does parent DOM element listens event twice?

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

If I trigger an event (say click) on an element.
Will it  be listen twice by it's parent (because of capture and bobble phase).
If yes, isn't it wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is event bubbling and capturing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking about event bubbling. It's not wrong, in fact it's there on purpose! The nice thing about bubbling is that you can cancel it at any point. So if something receives an event that it doesn't want to bubble up to its parent, you would just use:`e.stopPropagation()`, where `e` is your event.